# jquery infinitecarousel plugin, and dynamically loading overlapping data not working correctly

Tags: jquery, css, infinite-carousel

I'm using version 3.02 of the infinite carousel plugin from [here](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/)

to help me assemble some notes based on data from a db.  My problem is that the carousel left and right arrows do not show up, and I do not think the carousel effect is happening.  Here is how I am assembling my data:

```
<ul class="carousel">
<?php
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $url = htmlspecialchars($rows['stationery']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($rows['message']);
        echo "<li id=\"load_message\" style=\"background: url($url) no-repeat;\">";
        echo "<div id=\"message\">" . nl2br($message) . "</div>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
```

I see the background image with the text overlaid fine, but there are two problems:  the first is that the first image is displayed about 30 pixels lower than the second image.  The second problem is that I don't think the carousel plugin is being loaded and I don't see the left and right arrows.  I've looked in the NET tab of Firebug and it shows right.png and left.png being loaded. I load the plugin in the head of my doc, after jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.infinitecarousel3.min.js"></script>
```

And this is how I am evoking it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').infiniteCarousel({
        imagePath: 'images/examples/',
        transitionSpeed: 300,
        displayTime: 6000,
        internalThumbnails: false,
        thumbnailType: 'buttons',
        progressRingColorOpacity: '0,0,0,.9',
        progressRingBackgroundOn: false,
        margin: 10,
        easeLeft: 'linear',
        easeRight: 'linear',
        inView: 2,
        advance: 1,
        autoPilot: false,
        prevNextInternal: false,
        autoHideCaptions: false
    });
});
```

and lastly the css:

```
.carousel ul {
    height: 300px;
    width: 710px;
}

li#load_message {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 390px;
    width: 290px;
    position:relative;
}


#load_data {
    width: 710px;
    height: 460px;
}


#message {
    margin: 40px 10px 10px 30px;
    z-index:99;
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
}
```